# javacpp-presets-opencv,get pixel value of Mat?

Tags: opencv

I am using [javacpp-presets/opencv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv) which is a java wrapper for opencv. My question is how to get pixel value in Mat object or how to convert Mat object to multi-dimension java array?

I am using tensorflow java api for model inference.It needs `float[][][][]` java array as input argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved  see [this](http://bytedeco.org/news/2014/12/23/third-release/)

```
Mat bgr = new Mat();
UByteIndexer rgbaIdx = bgr.createIndexer();
System.out.print(rgbaIdx.get(0, 0, 0))
```